# Update/Replace data without form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

Please help how to update data in a database table without input form. I want to make the value on table become "0". I have created a controller:

```
function reset(){
    $data = array(
        'nomor_antrian' => '0',
        'jumlah_pengantri'  => '0'
    );

    $this->db->replace('antrian', $data);
}
```

The model :

```
function reset($id) {
        $data = array(
            'nomor_antrian'=>'0',
            'jumlah_pengantri'=>'0'
        );
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('nomor_loket', $id);
        $this->db->update('antrian');
    }
```

and this is the link button in the view section :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/reset'); ?>">Reset</a>
```

Thanks before.

Comment: Now, what is the issue?

Comment: the code above is correct or not or must add code to the model? Because the above code is still an error and the table value does not change.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Yes, `reset()` will be in model

Comment: In your `reset()` function you are got getting `$id`. So, error showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send `$id` to update record

Model code

```
function reset($id){
    $data = array(
        'nomor_antrian' => '0',
        'jumlah_pengantri' => '0'
    );
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('nomor_loket', $id);
    $this->db->update('antrian');
}
```

Reset link will be as follow

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/reset/'.$id); ?>">Reset</a> //$id is a parameter
```

Pass parameter to `reset()` function

Comment: I have added the model code that you provided, there stay error.

Comment: First, Your controller will call. And then from your controller model will call.